# How to stop websites taking control of iPhone audio?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, apple-music, music.app

How do I stop websites from taking control of audio and pausing Music app?

E.g. When I am listening to Apple Music on my iPhone and go to advert heavy websites like perezhilton.com and breatheheavy.com the websites repeatedly pause my music